# Working with broken HTML + BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup

I have some wonderfully broken HTML that, long story short, is preventing me from using the normal nested `<table>, <tr>, <td>` structure that would make it easy to reconstruct tables.

Here's a snippet with line numbers for reference:

```
1      <td valign="top">   <!-- closing </td> should be on 6 -->
2      <font face="arial" size="1">
3       <center>
4        06-30-95
5       </center>
6       <tr valign="top">
7        <td>
8         <center>
9          <font ,="" arial,="" face="arial" sans="" serif"="" size="1">
10          1382
11          <p>
12           (23)
13          </p>
14         </font>
15        </center>
16       </td>
17       <td>
18        <font ,="" arial,="" face="arial" sans="" serif"="" size="1">
19         <center>
20          06-18-14
21         </center>
22        </font>
23       </td>
24      </tr>
25    </td>    <!-- this should should be on 6 -->
```

The nesting of `tr`s within `td`s within `tr`s has no scheme to it whatesover, and is coupled with unclosed tags to boot.  The HTML tree in no way resembles how it is structurally rendered.  (In this case, I suppose there are technically no *missing* closing tags, but the actual rendering of the page makes it clear there should be no nested `td`s.)

However, **playing by the following set of rules would work in this case:**

- For any `<td>` that is followed by an opening `<td>` before its closing `</td>`, (i.e. any nested `td`) assume that the latter opening `<td>` (line 7) serves as closure for the first (line 1);
- Otherwise, just grab (open, close) `<td> ... </td>` tags as usual (where the opener and closer have no `<td>` in between them; example would be lines 17 & 23 above.

Desired result here would be something like:

```
['06-30-95', '1382\n(23)', '06-18-14']
```

How can this be addressed in BeautifulSoup?  I would show an attempt, but have picked through the docs and some of the source and not found much at all.

Currently this would parse to:

```
html = """
<td valign="top">
 <font face="arial" size="1">
  <center>
   06-30-95
  </center>
  <tr valign="top">
   <td>
    <center>
     <font ,="" arial,="" face="arial" sans="" serif"="" size="1">
      1382
      <p>
       (23)
      </p>
     </font>
    </center>
   </td>
   <td>
    <font ,="" arial,="" face="arial" sans="" serif"="" size="1">
     <center>
      06-18-14
     </center>
    </font>
   </td>
  </tr>
</td>
"""

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

strainer = SoupStrainer('td')
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser', parse_only=strainer)
[tag.text.replace('\n', '') for tag in soup.find_all('td')]

['   06-30-95        1382             (23)            06-18-14     ',
 '      1382             (23)      ',
 '      06-18-14     ']
```

And my issue with that result is not the whitespace; it's the repetition of substrings.  It almost seems like I'd need to recursively work upwards from the innermost tags, popping off each and working outwards.  But I have to guess there's more built-in functionality for dealing with missing closing tags (`handle_endtag` stands out from the `BeautifulSoup` constructor?).

Comment: What does it parse to?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For wonderfully broken HTML, there are two ways you can go about this.  First is to find the most consistently sets of opened/closed tags at the innermost possible nested level, and only just make use of the first one.  In this limited example provided it looks like the `<center>` tags will satisfy this.  Consider the following:

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> [t.find('center').text.strip() for t in soup.find_all('td')]
['06-30-95', '1382\n      \n       (23)', '06-18-14']
```

Alternatively, using `lxml` instead (as the [documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#specifying-the-parser-to-use) listed that as a method) may actually work better overall:

```
>>> soup2 = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
>>> [t.text.strip() for t in soup2.find_all('td')]
['06-30-95', '1382\n      \n       (23)', '06-18-14']
```

There are other methods that are covered in this thread: [Fast and effective way to parse broken HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33771317/fast-and-effective-way-to-parse-broken-html)

Answer (score 2):

Try this. It will fetch you the output you requested for:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'html5lib')
item = [' '.join(items.text.split()) for items in soup.select("center")]
print(item)
```

Output:

```
['06-30-95', '1382 (23)', '06-18-14']
```